# Extracting strings from JS file with gulp-angular-gettext does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I use angular-gettext-tools with @gabegorelick 's gulp-angular-gettext. Everyhing is okay with html files, but I fail to extract strings from js file. I tried both gettextCatalog.getString and gettext functions - together and separately - nothing worked.

My code for extraction (smth.js file) looks like this:

```js
  $scope.openCreateOfferPopup = function($event, buttonState) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    loadTypes();
    logger('openCreateOfferPopup');
    if (buttonState) {
      var params;
      if (!$rootScope.dashboard.spots || $rootScope.dashboard.spots.length === 0) {
        params = {
          title: 'Spots needed',
          content: gettextCatalog.getString(gettext("Oops! You need to add your spot before creating an offer!"))+
          '<br/>'+gettextCatalog.getString(gettext("Please, click on Create new spot button")),
          buttons: [{
            text: gettextCatalog.getString(gettext("Create spot")),
            href: '',
            'class': '',
            ngClick: 'openCreateSpotPopup($event)',
            ngController: 'SpotsController'
          }, {
            text: gettextCatalog.getString(gettext("cancel")),
            href: '#',
            'class': 'b-close'
          }]
        };
        DialogService.makeDialog(params, $scope);
        return;
      }
```

My gulp task looks like this:

```js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gettext from 'gulp-angular-gettext';
//import debug  from 'gulp-debug';

gulp.task('pot', function () {
    return gulp.src(['src/app/**/*.html','src/app/**/*.js',
            '!src/app/pages/static/acceptable_policy.html','!src/app/pages/static/legal.html',
        '!src/app/pages/static/privacy_policy.html','!src/app/pages/static/refund_policy.html',
        '!src/app/pages/static/terms_of_service.html'])
    //.pipe(debug({title: 'files to translate:'}))
    .pipe(gettext.extract('template.pot', {
        // options to pass to angular-gettext-tools...
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('po/'));
});
```

I am pretty sure that js file is passed to aangular-gettext-tools - I used gulp-debug to verify it.

There are no error messages. Everything is being extracted from html, but no entries from JavaScript.

Could you point me to the source of this problem?

I have gulp-angular-gettext@2.1.0 using angular-gettext-tools@2.1.13 and gulp 4.0.0-alpha.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the culprit. Angular-gettext-tools don't work with javascript ES7.
We had a piece of code:

```
async function loadTypes() {
  if ($rootScope.dashboard.types) return;

  const { categories } = await Api.offerTypes();
  $rootScope.dashboard.types = categories;
}
```

And it siliently died on `async function`. Possibly, old version of `espree` package from `angular-gettext-tools` is to blame.

I requested compatibility with ES7 and printing some debug info (to know that files could not be translated due to some error) here:
https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools/issues/140

Right now we are going to use babel to downgrade our javascript to processable version and use it for extraction.

**Update** to this question from official github:

> espree doesn't support it so there's probably nothing we can do. When
>   async/await is standardized, it will be added to espree, and we should
>   support it without any changes. Until then, use a transpiler like
>   babel before calling angular-gettext.